# PHP break out of array_reduce before looping through whole array

Tags: php

Coming from groovy where there is .find() and .findAll() methods on lists....

**array_filter()** seems PHP equivalent to groovy findAll.

```
  //groovy
    def allScorersOverFivePoints=scorers.findAll{
         it.points > 5
    }

   //PHP
   $allScorersOverFivePoints=array_filter($scorers,function($item){
                                                    return $item->points >5 } )
```

**array_reduce()** can return only one value or null (like find()), *but it is still going to loop through the whole array*.

```
    //groovy 
    def firstScorerOverZero=scorers.find{
                it.points > 0; 
    }

   //PHP- without manually looping will always go through the whole array??

   $firstScorerOverZero=array_reduce($scorers, function($carry,$item){ 
                                                 if($item->points > 0 && !isset($carry){
                                                     $carry=$item; 
                                                    return $carry;
                                               } ) }
                                    , null)
```

Is there any way to break out of these functional loops or am I required do do this manually...

```
 $firstScorerOverZero=null;
 $len=count($scorers);
 $i=0;
 while($i++<$len){
         if($scorers[$i]->points >0){
               $firstScorerOverZero=$scorers[$i];
               break;
          }
 }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with these functions?

Comment: Groovy is a Java framework. On the PHP side, there is another framework called Laravel that has a useful Collection class you can use standalone (just the class itself without the framework) and will give you similar capabilities: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html

Comment: The short and direct answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently defined following function in my global helper functions

```
function array_reduce_break(array $array, callable $callback, $initial = null, array $break_values = [])
{
  $result = $initial;

  foreach($array as $key=>$value)
  {
    $result = $callback($result,$value,$key);

    if(in_array($result,$break_values))
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to break out of the internal loops in the built-in `array_filter` and `array_reduce` functions. If it's important that your code does this, you will either need to create your own loop that emulates the behavior of one of those functions (while adding break) as you showed, or use a framework that provides that behavior as suggested in the comments. Of course, you'd need to verify that the framework actually implements the functions in the way you need it to.

In terms of performance, it makes sense to assume that code that does not iterate over the entire array will be faster, but this may be a microoptimization if the arrays you're working with aren't very large.

If you do want to do this, the loop you showed could be written *a little* more simply using `foreach` instead of `while`.

```
$firstScorerOverZero = null;
foreach ($scorers as $scorer) {
    if ($scorer->points > 0) {
        $firstScorerOverZero = $scorer->points;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this because it is a work-around but it does what you want:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

try {
    array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {    
        var_dump($item);
        if ($item === 4) {
            $carry = true;
        }
    
        if ($carry) {
            throw new Exception($item);
        }
    }, false);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    var_dump( $exception->getMessage() );
}
```

The output would be:

```
int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
int(4)
string(1) "4"
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I can use array_filter() on my 355,000+ arrays!